# Craft warning: Attempting to set settings on a plugin that doesn't have settings: [handle]

Tags: craft3, plugins, settings

I've noticed that this warning is being output in logs constantly

> Attempting to set settings on a plugin that doesn't have settings: tablemaker

The tablemaker plugin does not define a settings model and has both hasCpSettings and hasCpSection set to false, what is triggering the error?

It looks like the warning is coming from here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2eac9249964ccc553bf841c79b9ee44d58f16b61/src/base/Plugin.php#L189

- Craft CMS: 3.7.43
- tablemaker: 2.0.1

Comment: Which Craft and TableMaker versions? FWIW, TableMaker hasn't seen a commit in 4 years, so it's probably been abandoned at this point.

Comment: Sorry, Craft CMS 3.7.43 and tablemaker 2.0.1. Yeah tablemaker is abandoned, but doesn't mean it's still needed given there isn't a Craft native way of creating tables with definable columns and rows, without a custom fieldtype. There's promising development for Craft 4 as Verbb.io may take it over.

Comment: Not able to reproduce, using those versions. Which log files contain the error? Does it show up in the debug bar? Control panel or frontend?

Comment: It is showing up in the web.log, looks like this `2022-05-31 23:27:34 [-][43903][-][warning][application] Attempting to set settings on a plugin that doesn't have settings: tablemaker`

Comment: Interestingly, on a another environment with only a few plugins enabled I cannot replicate this error, so it would appear something on another project is triggering the warning to be logged.

Comment: Something in a custom module, perhaps?

Comment: I guess the one way to find out is either install all plugins and modules until the same error occurs or disable until it stops, fun!

Comment: Further development, I added a Craft::info log in the init function, it would appear this error is occurred before the init of tablemaker is even hit.
`2022-06-01 23:29:03 [-][43903][2afedbb0a2f0decdc178324fc73d64e4][warning][application] Attempting to set settings on a plugin that doesn't have settings: tablemaker
2022-06-01 23:29:03 [-][43903][2afedbb0a2f0decdc178324fc73d64e4][info][supercool\tablemaker\TableMaker::init] Table Maker plugin loaded
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, it would appear looking at project config that the field settings have been added as plugin settings under the plugins config key, looking at one project:

```
tablemaker:
    enabled: '1'
    licenseKey: null
    schemaVersion: 1.0.0
    settings:
      columnsAddRowLabel: ''
      columnsInstructions: ''
      columnsLabel: ''
      rowsAddRowLabel: ''
      rowsInstructions: ''
      rowsLabel: ''
```

Compared to a fresh install:

```
tablemaker:
    edition: standard
    enabled: true
    schemaVersion: 1.0.0
```

The project which this is happening on was originally a Craft 2 site, so it's possible it needs additional handling to cleanup. Looking at the Craft 2 database, there is indeed a setting key defined on the plugins table.

As these settings are meant to be for the field type, this looks like a mistake at some point, not sure how they've been able to be written to the plugins settings, but they can be cleaned up with a quick migration.

Comment: Nice sleuthing!